# How to play a video from an mp4 file instead when url isn't .m3u8 using Hls.js

Tags: javascript, html, m3u8, hls.js

I'm trying to either load a video when the source is an mp4 file (not url) and if it's not a mp4 file I want it to use hls.js to load from an m3u8 url source.

```
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.min.js"></script>
<video loading="lazy" style="border: none; position: absolute; top: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%" controls autoplay id="video"></video>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var videoSrcInHls = "<?php echo $video->getFilePath(); ?>";
    var videoSrcInMp4 = "<?php echo $video->getFilePath(); ?>";

    if(source.type !== 'video/mp4' && Hls.isSupported()) {
      var hls = new Hls();
      hls.loadSource(videoSrcInHls);
      hls.attachMedia(video);
      hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
        video.play();
      });
    }else{
      addSourceToVideo(video, videoSrcInMp4, 'video/mp4');
      video.play();
    }

    function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
      var source = document.createElement('source');
      source.src = src;
      source.type = type;
      element.appendChild(source);
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to use an else if statement with two conditions - source.type !== 'video/mp4' && Hls.isupported() for the first block and if its not a m3u8 url and is instead a filepath to play the video from the mp4 file instead